# How to remove something I have downloaded via curl

Tags: install, macos

I have followed this article: [link](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/) and ran the following command:

> curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6

How do I remove this, since I upgraded to Sierra and I already have php 5.6 version? If you include what happened when I executed this command, I'd be more than happy!

Edit for clarification:

1. I googled how to update php that comes with osx.
2. I opened this link I put above. And ran the command I mentioned.
3. And it told me it created a folder `/usr/local/php5-5.6.27-20161101-100213` and 'symlink'(?).
4. I updated to Sierra and the default php (that I was trying to "update") is now version 5.6.

I want to remove the php I installed from this article. I thought of deleting the folder I mentioned above, but I'm not sure that would do the thing. What about that symlink it made during the "installation"?

Comment: Which came first, the chicken (PHP 5.6) or the egg (Sierra with PHP 5.6)?  What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: @Allan Sorry I thought I explained my situation well. I have updated my question and included the steps I took.

Comment: What do you get when you type `which php`?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a shell script, `crater` (determine the impact crater of an install on a Unix filesystem) to deal with such poorly documented installation process:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253217/31707

Comment: You should run your _script_ through: [http://www.shellcheck.net/](http://www.shellcheck.net/)